# What do photos do?

Tags: word-request

What do photos do with their contents? They can picture, show, I wonder whether they depict. Lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/depict) it as "Represent by a drawing, painting, or other art form". I'm not sure any photograph is automatically art. What are other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the word show.

> These photos show my children when they were very young

However I did visit a few web-sites for exhibitions of photography and found the word "depict" used.

[Musee](https://museemagazine.com/culture/2018/4/17/exhibition-review-being-new-photography-2018-at-the-moma) gives this example.

> Aïda Muluneh works with hyperreal color and high fashion to redefine
> body image. In her abstract portraits, the Ethiopian photographer
> depicts regal black women painted bright shades of red, yellow, blue
> and white.

I think we could agree that these photographs are very artistic, and "depict" does seem the right word to use.

Comment: But can an unprofessional photo taken with a smartphone go with 'depict'?

Comment: All viewed images depict something, whether the creator was a professional, an amateur, or a machine. Artistic intent by the creator is not automatically implied.

Comment: I agree with Michael Harvey that the literal meaning of depict is satisfied by any such representation, professional or amateur, artistic or otherwise. However the word "depict" has a formal feel to it and I would not use it to describe a few family photos. I would never say "Have a look at these photos, they depict my grandchildren at various ages." To me that would sound pretentious.

Comment: @djna - but that was not the question.